# Accordion collapse, how to click open and close?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Accordion/collapse not working as i want, here's my code:

Here's the view with the JS in script tags:

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a href="#panelBodyOne" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Select Up To 3 Categories</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panelBodyOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <%= form.collection_check_boxes :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select a Category" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on('click', function() {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    })
</script>
```

Above that I have in the head:

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>

</head>
```

The way it's currently working is, load page, accordion/collapse is closed, click to open.  To close, you need to click away from it on the page for it to close.

I want it to click open and close only when i click the accordion/collpase itself.  How do i set this up?

I looked around and found this: https://codepen.io/delonnkoh/pen/LRWgPP
Which is essentially how i would like it to work.

I have tried all the results on stackoverflow and none seem to work.  The current code above is the closest i have come to successfully doing this but it closes only on an "off-click" and not when i click the accordion itself.

I've tried removing the links within the header since they're in my application, but same thing (so they're not needed).

I'm assuming my JS needs some help.  Anyone have the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you may use something like this;

```js
 $('.collapse').on('click', function() { //Add click handler on the parent div
        $('.panel-body').toggle('hide'); //Make the child hide or show when parent is clicked.
    });
```

Comment: it seems like it works, by only closing when clicking within the accordion.. which is a good start and just about good enough for my case - and then won't open again unless i refresh the page.